# The next js app does not send response back to browser when I dispatch in getInititalProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js, redux-saga, server-side-rendering

I am learning next js and using next with saga.

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-saga

In **other.js** file I moved **store.dispatch(startClock())** into getInititalProps(). Then refreshed the app, the request goes but server does not send response. Why ?

Similarly, the **index.js** page has also dispatched **loadData** to saga, but it never hangs. What is the different between **loadData** and **store.dispatch(startClock())** ? Why do they behave different in getInititalProps ?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you move **this.props.dispatch(startClock())** from **componentDidMount** to **getInitialProps** and call it like so **store.dispatch(startClock())**, it will run in the server instead of in the browser.

If it is in the server, the server cannot return a response since **getInitialProps** awaits for asynchronous dispatch and it is stuck-up in the saga.

If you will check the code in **saga.js**, notice the **runClockSaga** has a **while(true)** that runs infinitely if you ever dispatched the **START_CLOCK** action:

```js
function * runClockSaga () {
  yield take(actionTypes.START_CLOCK)
  while (true) {
    yield put(tickClock(false))
    yield delay(1000)
  }
}

function * loadDataSaga () {
  try {
    const res = yield fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const data = yield res.json()
    yield put(loadDataSuccess(data))
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(failure(err))
  }
}

function * rootSaga () {
  yield all([
    call(runClockSaga),
    takeLatest(actionTypes.LOAD_DATA, loadDataSaga)
  ])
}
```

You can now see the difference between dispatching the **loadData** and **startClock**, the **loadDataSaga** has no infinite **while (true)** loop, while the **runClockSaga** has.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: So, its necessary that I have to call only asynchronous apis or methods in getinitialprops ?

Comment: @Piyush, not necessarily, if you want the data to be available along with your html after a refresh, then put it in the getinitialprops, this is useful if you have a page that needs SEO or the content can be crawled by search engines like google. If you just want data on the client side, then you can just put it in the componentDidMount.